# Get accuracy for a boosted multinomial model

Tags: r, r-caret, multinomial, gbm

I am trying to find the accuracy of a boosted model. My code is as such:

```
wine.boost = gbm(as.factor(wine) ~ alcohol+hue, data = italiantrain,
distribution = "multinomial", n.trees = 5000 , interaction.depth = 2)

wine.boost.testpredict = predict(wine.boost, newdata=italiantest, 
n.trees =5000, type = "response")

confusionMatrix(wine.boost.testpredict, italiantrain$wine)
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
Error in confusionMatrix.default(wine.boost.trainpredict, italiantest$wine): 
the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

I'm not sure what to correct or what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well the error seems pretty straightfoward, can you share at least the structure of your datasets?

Comment: 'data.frame': 178 obs. of  8 variables:
     $ code   : Factor w/ 178 levels "ERA0174","ERA0176",..: 120 123 126 129 132 135 138 141 144 147 ...
     $ wine   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Barbera","Barolo",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $alcohol: num  14.2 13.2 13.2 14.4 13.2 ...
     $ sugar  : num  24.8 26.3 26.3 25.9 26 ...
     $ acidity: num  73.1 72.8 68.5 74.9 83.5 ...
     $ pH     : num  3.38 3.3 3.48 3.43 3.42 3.39 3.42 3.54 3.3 3.27 ...
     $ colour : num  5.64 4.38 5.68 7.8 4.32 6.75 5.25 5.05 5.2 7.22 ...
     $ hue    : num  1.04 1.05 1.03 0.86 1.04 1.05 1.02 1.06 1.08 1.01 ...

Comment: it would be helpful to have the data. 
the message seems to say that there is a difference in the number of factor levels in the prediction vector and the reference vector. you can check this with the command nlevels.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to be comfortable with your data is to not look at it:

```
> iris.boost = gbm(Species ~ ., data = iris,
+                  distribution = "multinomial", n.trees = 5000 , interaction.depth = 2)
> 
> iris.boost.testpredict = predict(iris.boost, newdata=iris[1:3, 1:4], 
+                                  n.trees =5000, type = "response")
> iris.boost.testpredict
, , 5000

        setosa   versicolor    virginica
[1,] 0.9987619 0.0011808413 5.722106e-05
[2,] 0.9994021 0.0004801001 1.177551e-04
[3,] 0.9993529 0.0005547632 9.236662e-05
```

You will have to convert the basic `gbm` output to a factor (or use `train`, which does it for you).